# Change integer into hex Ruby

Tags: ruby, perl, hex, pack

I am currently porting a perl project to ruby and all has been going fine until I reached this pack statement.

```
$move .= pack('W', int($length));
```

I understand what it's trying to do, but I can't find any documentation on the `'W'` option for perls pack method. So it is a bit hard to find a suitable replacement for ruby.

What this statement does is takes the integer, and converts it to a big endian hex format (I believe).

For example the integer 290 is converted to 0x122, and is then stored as `"2201"` in the variable `$move`

Although I cannot confirm that because I can't find documentation on `'W'` although it would make sense based on what the rest of the project is doing.

Does anyone know a ruby replacement method that would do the same?

edit: As per a comment below I have found it with some help.

`W An unsigned char value (can be greater than 255).`

Comment: Per http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html, `W` is "`W  An unsigned char value (can be greater than 255).`" Where did you look to not find it?

Comment: @theTinMan Well I'm ashamed... I looked on that exact page and missed it. I was expecting it to be in alphabetical order so I looked near the bottom for it. Thanks for this I'll try to find a replacement now.

Comment: 290.to_s(16) => "122" that converts an int to hex in ruby

Comment: @theTinMan: There is a reason for Stack Overflow's hyperlink facility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the format's introduction in 5.10, [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) says:

```
W  An unsigned char value (can be greater than 255).
```

For example, the following are equivalent:

- `pack('W', 0x2660)`
- `chr(0x2660)`
- `"\x{2660}"`

For all values of `$i`, `length(pack('W', $i))` is one.

---

What's the size of a character (string element) in Ruby? Are they 8 bits like C, or larger like Java (16) and Perl (32 or 64)?

If they are limited to 8 bits, there is no direct equivalent of that code in Ruby. You'll need to use an array instead of a string.

If Ruby's character are wide enough to contain the numbers in question (e.g. 290), then a look through the Ruby docs reveals the following:

```
i.chr
```

Comment: I've mistaken I accidentally pasted the wrong part of the perl code I was trying to port although this answer helped me realized my mistake. There was two pack statements one for values larger than 255 (two bytes), and one for values smaller (one byte). I accidentally used the one byte code with my two byte example. Although I managed to figure this out with help of this answer and the ruby docs.